# How Can I Implement a Type-Specific Debugger Keyboard Shortcut in VS Code?

Tags: java, python, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-code

I recently downloaded Visual Studio Code to program in Python and Java in a single IDE. Both require different debuggers, and it's inconvenient to go into debugger settings manually and select which debugger to use each time. My assumption of implementation in the image is within {}.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO6eV.jpg)

```
"key": "f6",
"command": "workbench.action.debug.start {specific debugger}",
"when": "!inDebugMode && {file_type}"
```

Comment: To my knowledge there is no vs-code command to start debugging a given launch configuration